# How to collect log output from executors in client mode on YARN?

Tags: logging, jenkins, apache-spark

If I have a spark job that is triggered from Jenkins, how do I get output from the spark workers to show up in the Jenkins logs? I am using yarn in client mode, not standalone spark.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yarn logs -applicationId` after the application is completed. If it's running, you can use the YARN console (usually on 8088 port) or access the logs on disk on the NodeManagers that manage the containers of the Spark apps.